# Need to populate table with Foreign and Primary key

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key, oracle12c

I need to create three tables from `all_tab_col` system table such that schema details are in one `schema_detail table`, table details are in `table_detail` table and column details are in `col_table`. These three tables are to be populated simultaneously through a stored procedure, with `PK(generated using SEQUENCE)` in `schema_detail` is `FK` in `table_detail` table and `PK(generated using SEQUENCE)` in `table_detail` is `FK` in `col_detail table`.

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? PK (generated using SEQUENCE) has changed in Oracle 12. Best if you add a tag with the Oracle version.

Comment: @wolφi using oracle12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is a set based language, so I would be tempted to solve your task with three set bases steps.

Some mock up tables (just add columns for the details you are interested in):

```
CREATE TABLE schema_detail (
  schema_id    NUMBER              GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  schema_name  VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)  NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT schema_detail_pk PRIMARY KEY (schema_id)
);

CREATE TABLE table_detail (
  schema_id   NUMBER,
  table_id    NUMBER              GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  table_name  VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)  NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT table_detail_pk PRIMARY KEY (table_id),
  CONSTRAINT table_detail_fk FOREIGN KEY (schema_id) 
    REFERENCES schema_detail(schema_id)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE INDEX table_detail_schema_idx ON table_detail(schema_id);
CREATE INDEX table_detail_name_idx ON table_detail(table_name);

CREATE TABLE col_detail (
  table_id   NUMBER,
  col_id     NUMBER              GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  col_name   VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)  NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT col_detail_pk PRIMARY KEY (col_id),
  CONSTRAINT col_detail_fk FOREIGN KEY (table_id) 
    REFERENCES table_detail(table_id)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE INDEX col_detail ON col_detail(table_id);
```

I'd fill the table `schema_detail` first. PK is generated automatically:

```
INSERT INTO schema_detail(schema_name)
SELECT DISTINCT c.owner FROM all_tab_columns c ORDER BY owner;

SCHEMA_ID SCHEMA_NAME
1         APPQOSSYS
2         AUDSYS
3         CTXSYS
...
```

Next, I'd fill the tables. The schema_id needs to be looked up the the `schema_detail` table. Again, we let the PKs be generated automatically:

```
INSERT INTO table_detail(schema_id, table_name)
SELECT DISTINCT s.schema_id, c.table_name 
  FROM all_tab_columns c
  JOIN schema_detail s ON c.owner = s.schema_name
 ORDER BY table_name;

SCHEMA_ID TABLE_ID TABLE_NAME
1         8403     WLM_CLASSIFIER_PLAN
1         8404     WLM_FEATURE_USAGE
1         8405     WLM_METRICS_STREAM
...
```

And last, I'd fill the columns:

```
INSERT INTO col_detail(table_id, col_name)
SELECT DISTINCT t.table_id, c.column_name 
  FROM all_tab_columns c
  JOIN table_detail    t ON c.table_name = t.table_name
  JOIN schema_detail   s ON c.owner = s.schema_name
 ORDER BY s.schema_id, t.table_id, c.column_name;
```

Does this solve your question or do you need a PL/SQL procedure?

Answer (score 1):

In case you insist on a PL/SQL stored procedure, I would code it along the lines of:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc IS

  schema_id schema_detail.schema_id%type;
  table_id  table_detail.table_id%type;

  FUNCTION lookup_insert_schema (p_schema_name VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN NUMBER 
  IS
    sid schema_detail.schema_id%type;
  BEGIN
    BEGIN
      SELECT schema_id INTO sid 
        FROM schema_detail 
       WHERE schema_name = p_schema_name;
    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO schema_detail (schema_name) 
        VALUES (p_schema_name) 
        RETURNING schema_id INTO sid;
    END;
    RETURN sid;
  END lookup_insert_schema;

  -- lookup p_table_name in table table_detail, if not found, insert it
  FUNCTION lookup_insert_table (p_schema_id NUMBER, p_table_name VARCHAR) 
    RETURN NUMBER 
  IS
    tid table_detail.table_id%type;
  BEGIN
    BEGIN
      SELECT table_id INTO tid 
        FROM table_detail 
       WHERE schema_id = p_schema_id 
         AND table_name = p_table_name;
    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO table_detail (schema_id, table_name) 
        VALUES (p_schema_id, p_table_name) 
        RETURNING table_id INTO tid;
    END;
    RETURN tid;
  END lookup_insert_table;

BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM all_tab_columns) 
  LOOP
    schema_id := lookup_insert_schema(r.owner);
    table_id  := lookup_insert_table(schema_id, r.table_name);
    INSERT INTO col_detail (table_id, col_name) 
      VALUES (table_id, r.column_name);
  END LOOP;
END myproc;
/
```

Comment: I have a question. why not do it in bulk insert why in loop with functions? any specific advantage?

Comment: Bulk insert would be even better and faster, of course. I tried to find a simple SQL and a simple PL/SQL answer. If you find a good answer, it is very welcomed on SO if you add an answer to your own question.